# TokenOfOwnerByIndex throws exception in one function but works on another with the same loop

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

I do Not understand how Erc721.tokenOfOwnerByIndex can not pass its require in this simple case:

```
function cancelAllSales() external onlyOwner {
    require(_powerSwitch == false, "System is still Online!");
    uint256 totalItemCount = nft.balanceOf(address(this));
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            uint256 tokenOfOwner = nft.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address(this),i);
            if(idToMarketItem[tokenOfOwner].seller != address(0)){
            nft.safeTransferFrom(
                address(this),
                idToMarketItem[tokenOfOwner].seller,
                tokenOfOwner
            );
            } else {
                nft.safeTransferFrom(
                address(this),
                owner,
                tokenOfOwner
            );
                }
            emit MarketItemRemoved(
                tokenOfOwner,
                idToMarketItem[tokenOfOwner].seller
            );
            delete idToMarketItem[tokenOfOwner];
    }
}
```

But in a simpler "fetch" function, called in the same state of the contract can work.
The results in the pictures are from consecutive runs with the same **5  ERC721 tokens** owned by the *address(this)* contract.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I renamed:  `uint256 tokenOfOwner = nft.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address(this),i);`
to `uint256 tokenId = nft.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address(this),i);`
I do not know why the name was the problem, but I am glad I tried it.